# SQL query is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This php is suposed to send five attributes {id, description, email, price, shape} to the *sales* table in the *salesinformation* database.

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'salesinformation');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link) {
    die('Cannot connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Cannot use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['description'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];
$value3 = $_POST['price'];
$value4 = $_POST['shape'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales (id, description, email, price, shape) VALUES ('', '$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')");

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

If I `echo $value` it prints out the correct information that I filled in my html form (So the part that extracts values from the HTML is working atleast). I run xampp and created the database with PhpMyAdmin, and when this PHP runs all I get is *Error: Query was empty* and nothing is added to the database at all.

What makes the mysql_query empty?

EDIT: I had missed a ' sign at one of the values.
Now instead I get this error message

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

Comment: So you call `mysql_query`, then you call it once again passing something that's definitely not a query into it? Have you checked `http://php.net/mysql_query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: What makes the mysql_query empty?

It's you, who calls `mysql_query` without a real query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales (id, description, email, price, shape) VALUES ('', '$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')");

if (!mysql_query($sql)){ // <---- look here
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

What we see in your code is that you pass `$sql` to `mysql_query` which isn't a valid query and you can check it with `var_dump($sql);`

Comment: Yeah I changed it to this:

`
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO sales (id, description, email, price,     shape) VALUES ('', '$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')");

    if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ID column from your query. Assuming you made made it a INDEX (and AUTO_INCREMENT) probably:). You can either remove it out the fieldlist, or instead of the '' put a NULL there :).

Comment: Yes I made it a INDEX and AUTO_INCREMENT with PhpMyAdmin editor. Well I removed the id and the '' value.

But I still get the new error message: *Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1*

Comment: First of all this is not the problem, and second of all - it's allowed to insert values into indexed columns (and auto_incremented as well, although it's a bad practice).